How to calculate the taylor series of $\int_{0}^{\arcsin{\frac{1}{x}}} \arccos{(x\sin{a})} da$?
I came across this integral while studying some inequalities involving sines: $$\int_{0}^{\arcsin{\frac{1}{x}}} \arccos{(x\sin{a})} da$$ No matter how much I tried I couldn't get a closed form for it so I plugged it into Mathematica and sure enough it was related to polylogarithms.
My question is, how might I calculate the Taylor series expansion of this integral about a point without knowing beforehand it could be expressed in terms of polylogarithms?(in terms of $x$)
I first tried plugging in the series for $\arccos$ and termwise integrating but that ended up with integrals of powers of sine which led to nasty nested sums. According to Mathematica it should have a nice Taylor expansion near infinity.
Thank you!!!

Let us first take the substitution $a=\arcsin{t}$, so $da = \frac{1}{\sqrt{1-t^2}} dt$. This transforms your integral into:
$$
I(x) = \int_{0}^{\frac{1}{x}}\frac{\arccos{xt}}{\sqrt{1-t^2}} dt
$$
Now, we caluculate the derivative:
\begin{align}
I'(x) &= \underbrace{-\frac{\arccos{(1)}}{\sqrt{1-1/x^2}} \cdot 1/x^2}_{=0} + \int_{0}^{\frac{1}{x}} \frac{\partial}{\partial x}\left( \frac{\arccos{xt}}{\sqrt{1-t^2}} \right) dt \\
&= \int_0^{\frac{1}{x}} -\frac{t}{\sqrt{1-t^2} \sqrt{1-t^2 x^2}} dt \\
&\overbrace{=}^{(1)} -\frac{\tanh ^{-1}\left(\frac{1}{x}\right)}{x}
\end{align}
Observe, that as $x\to \infty$ the expresion $I(x) \to 0$. So the constant term for the expansion about infinity is $0$. The other terms can be derived from the taylor expansion of $\frac{-\tanh ^{-1}\left(\frac{1}{x}\right)}{x}$.
NOTE: The last equality (1) can be evaluated by first subsituting $u=t^2$ and then using Euler substitution.

$I(x)=\displaystyle\int-\dfrac{\tanh^{-1}\left(\frac1x\right)}x\mathrm dx=\dfrac12\left[\mathrm{Li}_2!\left(\dfrac1x\right)!-\mathrm{Li}_2!\left(-\dfrac1x\right)\right].$
